# Dreamweaver Mail Error

Tags: php, email

Hi everyone so on my final project I made a 99 because I had a small error but I still can't figure out what the error is on my website. 
The error is

Warning: mail() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cafetownsend\getpassword.php on line 94
Having a problem sending your password.

```
  <?php if ($totalRows_rsgetpassword > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
  <p>
  <?php
  $name=$row_rsgetpassword['username'];
  $to=$row_rsgetpassword['email'];
  $password=$row_rsgetpassword['password'];
  $subject=["Your lost password"];
  $from= "From: example.com";
  $message="Hello $name, your password is $password.";
  if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$from))
  {echo "Your password has been sent to the email on the record.";}
  else
  {echo "Having a problem sending your password.";}
  ?>
  &nbsp;</p>
  <?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
  <p>
  <?php if ($totalRows_rsgetpassword == 0) { // Show if recordset empty ?>
  Your username was not found in our database. Please click <a   href="register.php">here</a> to register.
 <?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
 </p>
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: mail() expects parameter 2 to be string

So find where you call `mail()` and look at what it is.

> ```
> mail($to,$subject,$message,$from)
> ```

So it is `$subject`. Find that.

> ```
> $subject=["Your lost password"];
> ```

… and it is an array containing a string.

Why is it an array?

It shouldn't be an array.

Remove the square brackets so it is just a string.

Comment: Wow I was staring at it for an hour. I feel so stupid now. Thank you so much.